# Does the cardinality of coordinate projections of the rational points of affine varieties over finite fields also tend to $\infty$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields

We know (basically by Lang-Weil) that for an absolutely irreducible n-dimensional affine variety $V$ the cardinality $\#V(F_{l})$ tends to $\infty$ for $l$ large enough. We could now look at the set of rational points $V(\mathbb{F}_{l}) \subset \mathbb{F_{l}}^{n}$. I want to know whether it is true  that the cardinality of the projection to  any or at least one coordinate $\#\pi_{k}(V_{\mathbb{F}_{l}})$ also tends to $\infty$ or if it could be possible that there could be a strictly increasing sequence of primes $(p_{j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $\#\pi_{k}(V({\mathbb{F}}_{p_{j}})) < n$  for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Maybe one can formulate the question in a more modern algebraic geometric way to make the answer easier?

Comment: In this generality, no. Your $V$ could be contained in a hyperplane $x=0$ and projection on the $x$-axis will have only one point over any field.

Comment: Good point! Maybe I should ask if there will always be *one* coordinate for which the cardinality tends to $\infty$? Or is there also an obvious counter example?

Comment: As amended, is true. It's trivial for curves and the general case can be reduced to this case.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see why it is trivial for curves. Could you elaborate?